# How does this 2d array transposition work?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

So I've spent too long of a chunk of time trying to transpose (reverse amount of columns and rows of a matrix) a 2D array. We cannot use numpy or `zip` and found a useful snippet that works.

```
x = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]
new_x = [[x[j][i] for j in range(len(x))] for i in range(len(x[0]))][::-1]
```

I've been using a nested for loop -

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
```

Question 1: Can you please breakdown how the above functions the same as my code but is written differently (what exactly are the equivalents and how is it shortened this way)

Question 2: What exactly transposes it? I'm 99% sure it's the `[::-1]` and I know that -1 means we make one step backwards each loop but can't make the connection to how it basically rotates the array

Basically, please ELI5 and a small crash course would be super appreciated!

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Seems like it's missing `a = x; new_a = []` outside the loop and `new_a.append(a[j][i])` inside the loop, or something like that. You can [edit] to add it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Please limit the post to one question. #1 seems to be just explaining how a list comprehension works, which has been asnwered before on this site. For #2, the [[x[j][i] ...] is what achieves the transposition and the [::-1] just reverses the order (shouldn't actually be used). SO isn't a tutorial site, so we don't do crash courses. But we do answer well defined and specific questions. The links suggested by wjandrea should help in that regard.

Comment: Sorry yall, new to SO will take a deeper look into customs and whatnot, will look into list comprehension